# Android: snapshot of the root view (with ActionBar)

Tags: android, android-activity

I used to snap bitmaps of activities by taking their `content` view and drawing it:

```
View view = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content)

Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888
);

view.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
```

Now I'm using an ActionBar, and it's not nested under the `content` view, so it's left out. How can I obtain the **real** root view? Or snap a picture with the action bar in some other way, if that's not possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get a Bitmap for the entire window including ActionBar you can use the DecorView.

1. First you need to enable drawing cache

   ```
   getWindow().getDecorView().setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
   ```
2. get the bitmap

   ```
   Bitmap bmp = getWindow().getDecorView().getDrawingCache();
   ```
3. Use the bitmap elsewhere, I try this with a ImageView and works great.
4. disable drawing cache

   ```
   getWindow().getDecorView().setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
   ```

Comment: Question(s)! What are the side-effects of enabling the drawing cache? Why is it not enabled by default? Why do you not disable it afterwards and leave it as it was?

Comment: The sample code is just a way to get the snapshot of the screen, you are right, you need to handle the Bitmap and recycle it in your own app. Enabling drawing cache I think will use more memory for the bitmap and you should turn it off after you get the bitmap (sample updated).

Comment: `getDecorView()` returns a normal `View`, I think it's better to use OP's method of drawing it on a Bitmap backed Canvas, because then you can also manipulate it and you don't summon any unwanted side effects.